# Is there any way we can style input fields / button of component container?

Tags: adyen

How do I refer to the specific tags in the Adyen component in my css?

```
import AdyenCheckout from '@adyen/adyen-web';
import '@adyen/adyen-web/dist/adyen.css';
```

[For example, this button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X1Eh2.png)

This is inside my

```
        <div id="component-container"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can provide css rules that refer to the class you want to change, such as `adyen-checkout__button` to apply settings for any button created by adyen components or `adyen-checkout__button--pay` to change the pay button specifically.

Adyen provides a [list of css classes](https://docs.adyen.com/online-payments/drop-in-web/customization#drop-in-css-classes).

For card fields, these use iframes to gather details and [styling information has to provided when initializing the adyen component](https://docs.adyen.com/payment-methods/cards/custom-card-integration#styling).

```js
const checkout = new AdyenCheckout({
  paymentMethodsResponse: paymentMethodsResponse,
  clientKey: adyenClientKey,
  paymentMethodsConfiguration: {
    card: {
      styles: {
        base: {
          color: 'black',
          fontSize: '16px',
          fontSmoothing: 'antialiased',
          fontFamily: 'Helvetica',
        },
        error: {
          color: 'red',
        },
      },
    },
  },
  ...
});
```