# Custom input field text in Adyen card component in angular

Tags: angular, payment-method, adyen

I am trying to implement Adyen card component for card payment method. StyleObject works if I want to change the font, colour etc of the input fields for card number , security code etc. But I am unbale to change the input field label.I have tried using localisation and aria-label so far and they are not working.This is what my adyen.service.ts file looks like:

```
    export class AdyenService {

  translations={
    "en-GB":{
      "encryptedSecurityCode":"CVV/CVC",
      "payButton": "essfsdfsdf",
      "paymentMethods.moreMethodsButton": "More payment methods",    
    }
  };
  styleObject = {
    base: {
      color: 'black',
      fontSize: '16px',
      fontSmoothing: 'antialiased',
      fontFamily: 'Helvetica'
    },
    error: {
      color: 'red'
    },
    placeholder: {
      color: '#d8d8d8'
    },
    validated: {
      color: 'green'
    }
  };

  constructor(private readonly router: Router) { }
   ...

  getConfiguration(session: SessionResponseModel) {
    const configuration = {
      environment:environment,
      clientKey: clientKey,
      analytics: {
        enabled: true
      },
      ..
      },
      paymentMethodsConfiguration: {
        card: {
          hasHolderName: true,
          holderNameRequired: true,
          showPayButton: true,
          locale: "en-GB",
          translations: this.translations
          styles: this.styleObject

        }
      }
    };

    return configuration;
  }
}
```

Here are the links of angular docs I am following:
[localization](https://docs.adyen.com/online-payments/build-your-integration/?platform=Web&integration=Components&version=5.51.0#localization)
[custom Card component](https://docs.adyen.com/payment-methods/cards/custom-card-integration/#default-style)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place the`translations` attribute in the root of the Configuration object and use the label `creditCard.cvcField.title` to override the Security Code label

```
const translations={
    "en-GB":{
      "creditCard.cvcField.title":"CVV/CVC",
      "payButton": "essfsdfsdf",
      "paymentMethods.moreMethodsButton": "More payment methods",

    }
  }; 

const configuration = {
      environment: environment.options.adyen.environment,
      clientKey: environment.options.adyen.clientKey,
      locale: "en-GB",
      translations: translations,
      ...
```

Here is a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NNcgudu_hY4) explaining the different options to localize the Drop-in, on [GitHub](https://github.com/Adyen/adyen-web/blob/c6c19ac646a8a211d0416a462b2c2a2a722eff29/packages/lib/src/language/locales/en-US.json) you can find the labels you can customise.

Comment: thanks @BeppeC. Furthermore, if I want to override adyen default css styles e.g adyen-checkout__button --pay, Do I need to import '@adyen/adyen-web/dist/adyen.css' as well in adyen.component.ts file?

Comment: I am not sure, I am going to try it out, I don't remember exactly. If it is ok can you post a different question? I think you are facing something that other devs might have already solved. Thank you!

Comment: I have had a look and this is the closest to what I can get is this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66210862/is-there-any-way-we-can-style-input-fields-button-of-component-container. But I believe I will have to add it in either configuration object or card. No success yet